# Can you chain Beautiful Soup selectors?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
result = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "VjDLd"})
if len(result)>0:
    sub_result= result[0].find_next("div", attrs={"class": "SOGtLd"})
    if sub_result is not None:
        hyper= sub_result.find_next("a")
        if hyper is not None:
            return hyper.text
        else:
            return "NO GMB"
    else:
        return "NO GMB"
else:
    return "NO GMB"
```

I want to find an element that is a child of two previous selectors. I am not a big fan of how the code look, especially since I might need to make queries that will have even greater depth in the future. Is there a way you can do this in one line. For example.

```
soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "VjDLd"})[0].find_next("div", attrs={"class": "SOGtLd"}).find_next("a")
```

Something like this would work if all selectors in the chain find something, otherwise you would get an error. Is there something where you could make a sequence of selectors?

Comment: Could you provide the html and expected output, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but there are a lot of way. Help us to find the best one and improve your question, please.

If only one result expected:

```
soup.select_one('div.VjDLd div.SOGtLd a').get_text()
```

If more than one expected:

```
[a.get_text() for a in soup.select('div.VjDLd div.SOGtLd a')]
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="VjDLd"> 
    <div class="SOGtLd">
        <a>some text</a>
    </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

#if only one result expected
soup.select_one('div.VjDLd div.SOGtLd a').get_text()

#if more than one expected
[a.get_text() for a in soup.select('div.VjDLd div.SOGtLd a')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Both of the approaches will help me.